# R Rolling joins data.table alternative

Tags: r, join

Rolling joins are frequently needed when a time dimension is included. Consider the following two exemplary data sets covering "sales" and "commercials". I want to merge the most recent (i.e., prior or on the given date) commercial for every given sale:

```
sales <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2014-2-20", "2014-5-1", "2014-6-15", "2014-7-1", "2014-12-31")),
  saleID = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5")
)

commercials <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c("2014-4-1", "2014-7-1", "2014-9-15")),
  commercialID = c("C1", "C2", "C3")
)
```

In such situations, I find myself frequently in transferring my `data.frames` to `data.tables`, perform the join, and then back transform it to a `data.frame`. The code in this example could look as follows:

```
library(data.table)

cols <- colnames(commercials)

# change to data table for rolling join
df1 <- sales; setDT(df1)
df2 <- commercials; setDT(df2)
df1[, (cols) := df2[.SD, on=.(date), roll=Inf, mget(cols)]]

# revert to data frame
setDF(df1); sales <- df1
```

The procedure works as intended and produces the following output:

| **saleID** | **date** | **commercialID** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 2014-02-20 | NA |
| S2 | 2014-05-01 | C1 |
| S3 | 2014-06-15 | C1 |
| S4 | 2014-07-01 | C2 |
| S5 | 2014-12-31 | C3 |

However, ideally, I would like to avoid the transfer to the `data.table` environment and keep it is a `data.frame` in the first place. Are there any suitable alternatives to achieve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you not like keeping the class as a data.table?

Comment: @Cole The idea was mainly to avoid this switch from data.frame to data.table and back, particularly when working not generally with data.tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use dplyr's rolling joins, which have been available since dplyr 1.1.0

```
sales %>%
  left_join(commercials, by = join_by(closest(date >= date)))
      date.x saleID     date.y commercialID
1 2014-02-20     S1       <NA>         <NA>
2 2014-05-01     S2 2014-04-01           C1
3 2014-06-15     S3 2014-04-01           C1
4 2014-07-01     S4 2014-07-01           C2
5 2014-12-31     S5 2014-09-15           C3
```

Comment: This really looks like a good solution. Do you know if there is any chance to avoid creating both keys, e.g., .x and .y. Otherwise one needs, depending on the use case, always perform an additional rename and select step.

Comment: I would have suggested using `keep = FALSE` but that doesn't seem to work with rolling joins. For joins of this specific nature, you could maybe create a left_join wrapper `my_left_join <- function(x, y, suffix = c("", ".rhs.col"), ...){
  out <- dplyr::left_join(x, y, suffix = suffix, ...)
  dplyr::select(out, -dplyr::ends_with(".rhs.col"))
}`